# Is there a way to specify a different relative path with css?

Tags: html, css

Lets say you have:

```
<style><!--
  .foo {}
  .bar {}
--><style>

<img src="/img/image.png" style="foo" />
<img src="/img/image.png" style="bar" />
```

Is there any way on the css-side to have the first image come from http://example.com/1/img/image.png and the secound one from http://example.com/2/img/image.png?

Or else, is there any way to do this:

```
<style><!--
  .foo {[A]='http://example.com/1'}
  .bar {[A]='http://example.com/2'}
--><style>

<img src="[A]/img/image.png" style="foo" />
<img src="[A]/img/image.png" style="bar" />
```

Comment: no, this is clearly not the purpose of CSS which is styling

Comment: you can define variables in css btw;

Comment: @Leonardo You can but you cannot use it to set the `src` of an image.

Comment: @Terry thats right, I was trying to say using [backgroun url](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) in css instead of img tag d